# Grails Spring Security - principal is anonymousUser

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am working on a project on both my own local machine and a Linux server.

I have the following strange problem:

- On the server `authentication.principal` correctly returns the user that I have logged in with.
- On my own machine unfortunately "anonymousUser" is being returned.

The code is the exact same, the project is the same. The only difference are the operating systems and the underlying JDKs.

On my own local machine the only place where the correct principal is returned is within the `void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {` method. The `event.source.principal` is the correct one and not `anonymousUser`.

I have added a hack that seems to work and forces the correct principal. Could something be causing a logoff after the logon?

The below seems to temporarily solve the weird issue:

```
 void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
    log.debug("AuthenticationSuccessEvent, setting session")

    //Handles strange fringe case where personService.currentPerson returns anonymousUser even though login has taken place
    if(grailsApplication.config.debugForceReauthenticationWithPrinciple)springSecurityService.reauthenticate personService.getCurrentPerson(event.source.principal, true).username

    pService.setupSession(pService.getCurrentPerson(event.source.principal, true), session)
```

**To clarify, the problem is that `springSecurityService.getPrincipal()` returns `anonymousUser` even though I am logged in (on my own machine).**

Comment: @Burt Beckwith thanks for the edit. I rechecked the code and saw that I was typing it wrong ^^ :)

Comment: I have noticed that the failure is the first time a login is attempted. The second time it works.